# Problem with the packages file in my flutterflow project on Visual Code Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, package, flutterflow, pubspec.yaml

I have a problem with the packages file of my project for developping an app on Visual Code Studio, it says there are a lot of errors like Target of URI doesn't exists. I have tried many things with the help of Chat GPT but it does not seem to work at all...
I would really appreciate the help,
Thanks in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekQhr.png)

I tried to run flutter packages get, flutter packages upgrade and many other things, it also seems that there is a problem with the file pubspec.yaml because it always is mentionned.